# How do I override `as_view` in class-based views in Django?

Tags: django, decorator, overriding, django-class-based-views

I'm trying to introduce class-based views in my project. Looked good so far, until I found the following problem.

I'm using `django-navigation` to create breadcrumbs. It works like this: a view function gets decorated and this decorator introduces an attribute on that function called `breadcrumb`. In the template, current URL or its part get resolved and the resulting view get checked for this attribute. If it's there, it's evaluated and the result is the breadcrumb text.

Since class-based views are normally represented by the `as_view()` method, it seems I would need to decorate it, however, since it's a class method, I can't really access the instance there, which my breadcrumb of course depends on.

Attaching `breadcrumb` attribute to `as_view()` in the `__init__()` didn't work either, or I got the syntax wrong. **EDIT**: *Of course it didn't work, since I attached it to `as_view`, not to its return value.*

Any ideas how to properly integrate that breadcrumb decorator and class-based views?

Answer (score 11):

I've solved this now like this. I've put my `breadcrumb` routine in a method on a child class and overridden `as_view` in my base view. Also used a trick from the actual `as_view` to get a `self` pointer.

```
@classonlymethod
def as_view(cls, **initkwargs):
    self = cls(**initkwargs)
    view = super(MyBaseView, cls).as_view(**initkwargs)
    if hasattr(self, 'breadcrumb') and callable(getattr(self, 'breadcrumb', None)):
        return breadcrumb(self.breadcrumb)(view)
    return view
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could do something like this in urls.py:

```
the_view = ListView.as_view(...)
the_view = the_decroator(the_view)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', the_view, name='app_index'),
    ...
)
```

The as_view method returns a callable, and that can be decorated. The '@'-syntax is just a shortcut for what is done on line 2.

Comment: Can you do this in a single line? `url(r'^$', the_decorator(ListView.as_view()), name='app_index')`?